# VBA Runtime 424: How to use dim frm & display Userform

Tags: excel, vba

Errormsg: Runtime 424: Object Required.

where is my mistake?
Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AMain()
Dim frm As New UF
frm.Show
Set frm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Wanted to display my UserForm.
(ExcelVBA 2016)

Comment: Welcome to SO Devo44. I don't get any errors running the code you've pasted. I suspect the real issue is in your form. When you create/show the form, some code might be running there. Can you update your question to include the form code?

Comment: Hint: In the VBE editor, Goto Tools->Options. In the "General" Tab, check "Break in Class modules". That forces the runtime to stop with the form code.